# Download SVG - Error in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

In Google Earth Engine, when I download a chart as SVG, it doesn't seem to work somehow. I get an error when I open the downloaded file.

```
This page contains the following errors:
error on line 1 at column 312: AttValue: ' expected
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Any alternative or a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

I see the same problem. This appears to be a bug, which I have now reported. Once it is fixed the button should work as expected.